# How to disable groups of frames based on button click?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I'm trying to make a light/dark mode configuration for my app. My idea is to make two groups of frames: one light, another dark. Upon the user clicking a small button, light would turn to dark. So the light group of frames gets disabled, and the user is taken to the first frame in the dark group. And if the button is clicked again, the dark group gets disabled, and the user is taken to the first frame in the light group.

Is there a way I can make something like this happen? I know it seems a bit complex, if so, is there an easier way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: It is more easier to use `ttk.Notebook` for switching frames instead of enabling / disabling group of frames.

Comment: By "disable" do you mean "remove from the window"?

Comment: Are you aware of the `ttk` widgets? You can change the background and foreground of all widgets of a particular type with a single line of code once you have it set up properly. There's no reason to create two identical sets of widgets that only differ in their color.

Comment: I'm not aware of `ttk` widgets. I will check them out shortly. I meant by "disable" to activate one group of frames (the 'light' mode frames) if a button is clicked, and activate another group (the 'dark' mode frames) if a button is clicked again. If I want light mode, I wouldn't want Tkinter to switch to a dark frame, so I don't want to switch to them.

Answer (score 0):

For example:
button to change background
you can change the function however you want

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x480")
root.title("Dark Theme")
btn = Button(text="On", command=lambda: on(True))
btn.pack()
btn = Button(text="Off", command=lambda: off(True))
btn.pack()
def on(which):
    if which:
        root.configure(bg='black')
    else:
        print("")

def off(which):
    if which:
       root.configure(bg='white')
    else:
        print("")
    
root.mainloop()
```